# Why does math.Pow10(e int) returns float64 rather than int64?

Tags: math, go

Since parameter `e` is `int`, why not just return an `int64`? Is there any special reason for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2 reasons:

First, the parameter may be negative too, in which case the result is a fraction number between `0` and `1`, so a `float64` return value is not just justified but needed.

```
fmt.Println(math.Pow10(-1))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lSRZApp6pO)):

```
0.1
```

Second, almost<sup>*</sup> every function of the [`math`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/) package returns value(s) of type `float64`, adding one that doesn't would break "consistency".

<sup>[*] Few exceptions include functions like [`Float32frombits()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float32frombits) and [`llogb()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Ilogb) where the deviation is justified.</sup>